# How to reshape vertical table

Tags: r, reshape

I would like to reshape the table with patient information. I have tried `xtabs` from **base R** and `acast` from **reshape2**, but couldn't get the results. My table looks something like this:

| var1 | id | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patient name 1 | 0021 | 7.0 | 167.3 |
| Drugs | NA | 3.0 | 15.8 |
| Medical products | NA | 1.0 | 150.0 |
| Solutions | NA | 3.0 | 4.5 |
| Patient name 2 | 0154 | 11.0 | 792.0 |
| Drugs | NA | 7.0 | 37.4 |
| Surgical materials | NA | 4.0 | 754.6 |

As you can see some patients might have surgery some don't, in this situation it is not even mentioned under the patient's name. And the number which is next to id **0021** and **0154** is the *total number of quantity* and *total price* for that patient, this information is not needed in the new table. I think totals can be easily calculated later. The final table should look like this:

| ID | Drugs price | Medical products price | Solutions price | Surgical materials price | Drugs quantity (etc.) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0021 | 15.8 | 150.0 | 4.5 | 0 | 3.0 |
| 0154 | 37.4 | 0 | 0 | 754.6 | 7.0 |

So, the function has to fill missed variables with 0, and have to be vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  fill(id) %>% 
  filter(var1 %in% c("Drugs", "Medical products", "Solutions", "Surgical materials")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var1, 
              values_from = c(price, quantity), 
              names_glue = "{var1} {.value}",
              values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(id = sprintf("%04d", id))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  id    `Drugs price` `Medical products p~ `Solutions price` `Surgical materials ~ `Drugs quantity` `Medical products q~ `Solutions quant~ `Surgical materials ~
  <chr>         <dbl>                <dbl>             <dbl>                 <dbl>            <dbl>                <dbl>             <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 0021           15.8                  150               4.5                    0                 3                    1                 3                     0
2 0154           37.4                    0               0                    755.                7                    0                 0                     4
```

Comment: It gives me this error: Error in UseMethod("fill") :    no applicable method for 'fill' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Is your data a `data.frame` or `tibble` object?

Comment: Imported from excel. typeof shows it as a list.

Comment: You'll want to convert it to a `data.frame` or `tibble` using `as.data.frame()` or `as_tibble()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can `fill` the `id` values and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  fill(id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var1, values_from = c(quantity, price), values_fill = 0)
```